# Volley JsonArrayRequest can not send parameter to Server

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a `SearchActivity`  . i must send a parameter like **search keyword** to server and receive JsonArray .

I used this code for `JsonArrayRequest` :

```
JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("response : ",response.toString());
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        params.put("test", "ok");
        return params;
    }
};


AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

in server PHP file :

```
$keyword=  @$_POST["test"];
if($keyword=="ok")
{
echo'
[  
   {  
      "name":"name 1 ",
      "img":"1.jpg",
      "info":"hello",
      "id":"eee"
   },
   {  
      "name":"name 2",
      "img":"2.jpg",
      "info":"hello",
      "id":"222"
   }
]
';
}
```

But server dont send anything for app

i tested it by StringRequest it work fine but in JsonArrayRequest it not work

When i use JsonArrayRequest it seem parameters not seted

pls help

Comment: Follow the Answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212109/error-404-when-receive-post/37265023#37265023) I hope it will work for U.

Comment: sorry ! in this link used AsyncTask  . it's bad idea i must use volley library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use `StringRequest`?

If your response is `JsonArray` or `JsonObject` you can get it from `StringResponse` as well.

```
String response;

JSONArray arrayResponse = new JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: because it return me a String value But i need JsonArray

Comment: @Abbas Nikzad I Updated my answer check it

Comment: i'll test it , wait . i'll come back and give result !

Comment: when i used stringrequest I get an error :the response is array .how fix it?

Comment: @zeynab farzaneh What's your error? and for better answer take it as a new question

Answer (score 1):

If your project uses mcxiaoke's library, you will find inside `JsonArrayRequest.java` file there's a constructor as below

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
            errorListener);
}
```

Use this for your request.

If your app uses Google's volley library (not JAR file), you will need to add that constructor into `JsonArrayRequest.java` file, or you may try using `getBody()` instead of `getParams()`.

---

UPDATE: use the following sample

```
...
JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
try {
    requestBody.put("key1", "value1");
    requestBody.put("key2", "value2");  
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            // do something
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // do something
        }
    };
    // Executes request
    requestQueue.add(request);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // do something
}
...
```

Comment: i downloaded jar file of library i dont know is mcxiaoke's or google

Comment: You can press Ctrl-B at JsonArrayRequest to open that file

Comment: the file package name is package com.android.volley.toolbox

Comment: No, I mean you open that file to look for the constructor as in my answer.

Comment: in my JsonArrayClass i have meny constructor , i copied : 
`public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(0, url, (String)null, listener, errorListener);
    }`

Comment: `public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (String)null, listener, errorListener);
    }`

Comment: `public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest == null?null:jsonRequest.toString(), listener, errorListener);
    }`

Comment: Just need look for the one I said

Comment: `public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest == null?null:jsonRequest.toString(), listener, errorListener);
    }`

Comment: `public JsonArrayRequest(String url, JSONArray jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(jsonRequest == null?0:1, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }` AND




    
`public JsonArrayRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(jsonRequest == null?0:1, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }`

Comment: all of them are in my JsonArrayReq Class file

Comment: It has. So you can use the one as in my answer

Comment: i did it , but my problem not solved ! in server isset() method return me null

Comment: In your question, you use another constructor, not the one I said

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below link  is much  similar to you question.

[Why is Volley's onResponse not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614675/why-is-volleys-onresponse-not-called/36614984#36614984)